# Json Mapping Exception in parsing a tag in an API in java

Tags: java, pojo

Pojo class:

```
public class PojoA{
 Individual individual;
}

public class Individual {
String a;
String b;
}
```

I create a request to hit an external API. I get the response as:
{"individual": "    "}.

I have to handle it in Java. So that it does give the below exception-
Can not construct instance of com.airtel.pe.ecaf.butterfly.postpaid.dto.Individual: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from a String value ('    ')

Please help. 
In getting response from an API, I use- 
response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestHeader, responseType, request);

Please help

Comment: can u share the request json that your post call is expecting

Answer (score 0):

Create object of Individual and this in PojoA and use Gson library or Json to convert it into json and use in request

```
Individual individual = new Individual("a" , "b");
PojoA pojo = new PojoA();
pojo.setIndividual(individual)

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(pojo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add two constructors in your POJO files :

1. Default constructor
2. Parameterised constructor (super)